# Drawing rectangles, starting from a line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm still a novice in tikz, and I would like to ask how to draw and fill the rectangle, as in the following image:

[image]

Here's my very simple MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings} 
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\coordinate (A) at (0,2);
\coordinate (B) at (4.5,0);
\coordinate (C) at (2,4);
\coordinate (D) at (4,-1.4);

\draw (A)--(B) node[anchor=north west] {\small $p'x=\alpha$} coordinate[midway] (M) coordinate[pos=0.85](k);
\draw[-latex] ($(M)!0cm!270:(B)$)--($(M)!2cm!90:(B)$) node[anchor=north west]{$p$};

\shade[upper right=gray!,lower left=gray!, fill opacity=0.3] (3,3) rectangle (M);

\node[dot=below left:$x_{0}$] at (M) {};
\draw[-latex] (M)--(C) node[pos=0.95, anchor=north east] {\small $x_{1}$};
\draw[-latex] (M)--(D) node[pos=0.95, anchor=north east] {\small $x_{2}$};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Is there a better and faster way to draw this, maybe by way of "path"?

Comment: Most commands are actually \path commands:  \draw is \path[draw], \fill is \path[fill], \node is \path node, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does what you want. I've only included the `dot` (M) into the command which draws the arrow from `M` and a possible code to draw the gray rectangle:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings} 
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\coordinate (A) at (0,2);
\coordinate (B) at (4.5,0);
\coordinate (C) at (2,4);
\coordinate (D) at (4,-1.4);

\draw (A)--(B) node[anchor=north west] {\small $p'x=\alpha$} coordinate[midway] (M) coordinate[pos=0.85](k);
\draw[-latex] (M) node[dot=below left:$x_{0}$] at (M) {} --($(M)!2cm!90:(B)$) node[anchor=north west]{$p$};

\fill[gray!30] (A) -- ($(A)!2cm!-90:(B)$) -- ($(B)!2cm!90:(A)$) -- (B)--cycle;

%\shade[upper right=gray!,lower left=gray!, fill opacity=0.3] (3,3) rectangle (M);

%\node[dot=below left:$x_{0}$] at (M) {};
\draw[-latex] (M)--(C) node[pos=0.95, anchor=north east] {\small $x_{1}$};
\draw[-latex] (M)--(D) node[pos=0.95, anchor=north east] {\small $x_{2}$};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I tried to add node[pos=1, anchor=north west]{$p'x\leq \alpha$} after the \fill command to insert a label, but it doesn't show up, as if it was hidden under the rectangle, maybe this is related to opacity?

Comment: @Nenne If you added the `node` into the `fill` command, the contents is written in gray and you won't see it. Change the color to black.